# Load html and all js files from the server not from browser cache

Tags: javascript, html, caching

I want to ensure users always get the latest version of my code.
However setting it up so that browsers do not cache the files is bad 
as it would need to be loaded fresh every page view. I want to ensure it doesn't use a cached copy from a previous release.

One way I have seen involves changing the filename on each release, but don't know how to do it for index.html? I have couple of js files in index file.

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="js/gen_validatorv31.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: This seems like a duplicate. Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7413234/how-to-prevent-caching-of-my-javascript-file

Comment: Asked many times here... build system with querystring is best bet

Comment: If you version your assets (scripts, css, etc) and put then in a different path (e.g. `/css/2.x.x/file.css`) then even if the index.html is loaded from cache it will only load the relevant assets. When a new version of index.html is requested, new versions of the assets (with a different path) will be loaded.

Comment: I might also add it depends on what your using to develop your site (Ruby/Django/ASP.NET/etc). Each has a well-regarded method of cache-busting on each version.

Comment: Regarding your index.html : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13321335/load-index-html-every-time-from-the-server-and-not-from-cache

Comment: if i use meta tag will it works for js file also or shall add the random number to the js file